# How to import eclipse android project to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I followed the directions in this link [Migration from Eclipse to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

then I able to import the **build.gradle** to Android Studio. But I cannot run the project, there are also no Android Manifest, Activities, and layouts in the imported project.

My project works fine in Eclipse, and it includes modules.

How to run the imported android project from exported eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

**Export from Eclipes:**

1. Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).
2. In Eclipse, select **File > Export.**
3. In the window that appears, open **Android** and select **Generate Gradle build files.**
4. Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click **Finish**.

Import in Android Studio

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the **Welcome to Android Studio**   window.
2. Click **Import Project.**
3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click **OK.**
4. In the following dialog, leave **Use gradle wrapper** selected and click **OK**. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)

[Source](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)